# Get end nodes when using *

Tags: neo4j

Lets say I have points a, b, c, d and a->b->c->d is related with next. Below is merge command for it.

```
merge (a:point{id:'a'})-[:next]-(b:point{id:'b'})-[:next]-(c:point{id:'c'})-[:next]-(d:point{id:'d'}) return a, b, c, d
```

[Neo4j image of the merge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GdqMA.png)

What I am looking for is a way to get all the points between a and d. Using below query I get the relationships, but how can I get list that contains b, c?

```
match p=(start:point)-[:next*]-(end:point) 
   with *, relationships(p) as r 
   where start.id ='a' and end.id = 'd'
return start, r, end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
RETURN nodes(p)[1..-1]
```

to get the nodes except the first and last one.

Comment: Great!! thanks a bunch!! worked perfectly.